# Set strict mode in powershell for all modules

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm using following structure in my scripts:

```
HighLevel.ps1
  LowLevelModule1.psm1
  LowLevelModule2.psm1
  ...
```

Now, I'm setting strict mode in ps1 file to get at least some type-safety during runtime. Unfortunately, cllaing `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` will enable strict mode only for current scope and all child scopes (this is by design. Proof: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx).

As far as I understand current PS architecture, changing strict mode in ps1 file changes script level configuration. But modules has its own script scope so modules does not inherit parents rules.

As a workaround I can put `Set-StrictMode` to every PSM1 files, but it seems not very best approach because I would not be able to give a chance to the client of my module to decide, turn on strict mode or not.

The same issue exists for `$VerbosePreferences` configuration. This configuration is also enabled per scope, so I have to propagate this information across module boundaries some how.

Any suggestions how to change strict mode and verbose preference globally?

P.S. Changing $profile for this purposes is not an option.

Comment: I think setting `$global:VerbosePreference` globally should work for modules. As for the strict mode, it does not. BTW, I added the strict mode issue to [PowerShellTraps](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps), see *Strict-mode-is-not-propagated*.

Answer (score 4):

If these are modules you are writing yourself, then I suggest that you set the strict mode that you want inside the module. It will only apply to the code inside the module, so the setting for code outside the module, set by the caller, is irrelevant.

If these are modules written by others, then you do not want to change the strict mode (or lack thereof) on that code, because it was not tested with strict mode on and could break by doing so.

Comment: I'm ok to change the strict mode, but do you have any ideas with $VerbosePreferences? This is definitely that I would like to change in one place.

Comment: What's the goal? If you set `$VerbosePreference` to (say) `'Continue'`, then the functions exposed by the module will act as though you called them with `-Verbose`.

Comment: I'm trying to turn on "logging" for all my modules in the root ps1 script.

The problem that when the function from the module will call function from another module, then it would call it without -Verbose flag. And to turn verbose messages I have to propagate this flag across multiple calls via : -Verbose:($VerbosePreference -eq 'continue') or using some other trick.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you're gong to get around the scope issue. If you can edit the .psm1 files, you could set `$VerbosePreference` there, or [use `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx) to set it.